# How to change font-size of dynamic text unitl the text is stored in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I have a span in div, and dynamic text, like this:

```
<div>
<span>
    dynamic text
</span>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change font-size until *dynamic text* is stored in one line (I mean, no line wrapping)?

Comment: you can check the value inside your span using .text() with a certain predefined value and change it's font size using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the value inside the span (you must trim it to avoid preceding spaces).

```
var result = $("div > span").text().trim();
```

Then simply check the result with your predefined value and change the font-size

```
if(result == "dynamic text"){
    $("span").css("font-size", "50px");
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aaWx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function adjust() {
    var text = document.getElementById('t');
    var input = document.getElementById('a');
    text.innerHTML = input.value;
    var fontSize = parseFloat(text.style.fontSize);
    fontSize -= 0.1;
    text.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <span id="t" style="font-size: 18px">
        dynamic text
    </span>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="a" onkeydown="adjust()"/>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set overflow of div to hidden.

```
<div  id="Div" style="overflow:hidden ">
 <span id ="Span" onclick="resize()">
   DynamicText
 </span>
</div>
```

The javascript code decrements the font size of the span until the width of the span is less than that of the containing div :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
{
    while(parseInt($('#Span').width()) > parseInt($('#Div').width()))
    {
        $('#Span').css('fontSize', (parseInt($('#Span').css('fontSize'))-1) +'px');
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6H7c/70/)